# How to switch beteen Multiple Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, switching

I am Having 8 Screenns.I have prepared  8 Activities for that.
In First Activity I have given this code
To Switch from Ist Activity to IInd
On Image Button gives On Click

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
     v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
});
```

What to do to Switch on 2nd Activity to 3rd Activity ,
3rd Activity to 4th Activity , and so on.

Pls help me in regard.

Comment: why not writing the same code/onClick in each activity (with argument as subsequent)?

Comment: This looks like horrible code. Have you gone through a single tutorial on how to switch start activities?

Answer (score 7):

Here's 1 way you could do it below. In this example, you'd put 3 buttons on the screen.  These are buttons I defined and laid out in my XML file.  Click on any of the 3 different buttons, and it takes you to the corresponding activity.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

      // Here is code to go grab and layout the Buttons, they're named b1, b2, etc. and identified as such.     
    Button b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Button b2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    Button b3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);

// Setup the listeners for the buttons, and the button handler      
    b1.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);
    b2.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);   
    b3.setOnClickListener(buttonhandler);
}           
    View.OnClickListener buttonhandler=new View.OnClickListener() { 

   // Now I need to determine which button was clicked, and which intent or activity to launch.         
      public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) { 

 // Now, which button did they press, and take me to that class/activity

       case R.id.b1:    //<<---- notice end line with colon, not a semicolon
          Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(yourAppNamehere.this, theNextActivtyIwant.class);
    YourAppNameHere.this.startActivity(myIntent1);
      break;

       case R.id.b2:    //<<---- notice end line with colon, not a semicolon
          Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(yourMainAppNamehere.this, AnotherActivtyIwant.class);
    YourAppNameHere.this.startActivity(myIntent2);
      break;  

       case R.id.b3:  
                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(yourMainAppNamehere.this, a3rdActivtyIwant.class);
    YourAppNameHere.this.startActivity(myIntent3);
      break;   

       } 
    } 
};
   }
```

Basically we're doing several things to set it up.  Identify the buttons and pull them in from the XML layout.  See how each has an id name assigned to it.  r.id.b1 by example is my first button.

Then we set up a handler, which listens for clicks on my buttons. Next, need to know which button was pushed. The switch / case is like an "if then".  If they press button b1, the code takes us to what we assigned to that button click.  Press on b1 (Button 1), and we go to that "intent" or activity we've assigned to it.

Hope this helps a little Don't forget to vote up the answer if it's of any use.  I'm just getting started on this stuff myself.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

let's try to use the code snippet from below url and go through flags from developer guide.

[Android; How can I initialise state in one activity, then have another refresh that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750776/android-how-can-i-initialise-state-in-one-activity-then-have-another-refresh-th/3751190#3751190)