# A->B->C->D Activity Flow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Bear with me, as this is my first Android app. :)

Essentially, I would like the user to be able to extract some information (stored as an array) from a photo and save the array in persistent memory.

The app would have four screens (ABCD), that would be as follows:

**A**:  User has three choices: take a picture with the camera, select one from memory, or view saved arrays that have already been made with the program.
**B**:  Top half of the screen is a preview of the selected photo and bottom half is an area where the user can select variables.
**C**:  User sees the resultant array, with the option to save it.
**D**:  View saved arrays.

Essentially, I just want back/next buttons between each activity, with the state of the global array saved when you hit back/next. I've looked through dozens of examples on SO and the closest I've seen is:
A->B
A->C
with activities B and C returning some value to A.

Are there any examples like this out there that may help me? Ashamedly, I have been working on this for hours.

Thanks!

### tl;dr:

I would like to have the activity flow A->B->C->D, with back/next buttons to go to each adjacent activity, including the ability to go A->D and D->A.

Comment: are you asking about general `Activity` to `Activity` workflow? or are you asking about how to launch a Camera preview activity?

Comment: Sorry Alex. I thought that I was being helpful by giving context, and I probably gave too much info. The most important thing right now is that I get the Activity workflow happening. I won't be working on the camera stuff for a while yet :)

Thanks for responding.

Comment: is there any specific SDK that you are targeting? it sounds like you might want to consider using a `ViewPager` or some sort of tab layout.

Comment: I will check out ViewPager and get back to you if it is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Android application you make can re-use activities made available from other applications.  It seems like most of what you need has already been implemented by the Android team (that is, the default Camera preview `Activity` that pops up whenever you launch the default Camera application). Check out this [**tutorial**](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html) for details on how to set this up in your application properly.

The tutorial also explains how to customize your own Camera preview `Activity` (although this might be a little harder if it is your first time writing an Android application).

Comment: Thanks again, Alex. I found an example of what I need at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855729/how-to-switch-beteen-multiple-activities-in-android

Comment: sorry I ended up answering the wrong question :P. let me know if I help in any way!